# WCF Services Ajax/jQuery Call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, wcf

I'm new at this thing of web services.

I'm trying to put my web service working, but with no success. I've tried to change web.config and the web service, and I can't call it anyway.

> *Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.*

**Web.config**

```
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHTTP">
          <enableWebScript />
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHTTPP">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WebHTTPP" name="eficduarte.api.newsletters">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebHTTP" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="eficduarte.api.newsletters" />
      </service>
</services>
</behaviors>
```

**WebService** that i'm trying to call from URL

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/ListarSubscricoesActivas", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public object ListarSubscricoesActivas()
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like following

```
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHTTP">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>        
      </endpointBehaviors>
```

Also add binding configuration section for `bindingConfiguration="Binding"`